PTRACE_SYSCALL appears to be skipping calls (tgkill in particular)
I'm trying to catch when a multi-threaded program has an uncaught exception with ptrace (later on I'll perform a backtrace with libunwind), but I seem to be having trouble with that. It seems like ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0) is skipping tgkill or isn't showing all of the system calls.
I'm fairly certain that tgkill is the function that I need to be looking for because of running strace on this simple program:
throw.cpp:
#include <thread>
void function()
{
  cout << "In thread function\n";
  throw 42; //oops!
}
int main()
{
  thread t(function)
  t.join()
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

end of strace throw:
--- 8< snip 8< ---
[pid  3866] write(2, "terminate called after throwing "..., 48terminate called after throwing an instance of ') = 48
[pid  3866] write(2, "int", 3int)          = 3
[pid  3866] write(2, "'\n", 2'
)          = 2
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1], [], 8) = 0
[pid  3866] getpid()                    = 3865
[pid  3866] gettid()                    = 3866
[pid  3866] tgkill(3865, 3866, SIGABRT) = 0
[pid  3866] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  3866] --- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=3865, si_uid=1001} ---
[pid  3865] <... futex resumed>)        = ?
[pid  3866] +++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
+++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++                                                                                                                                                                                                      Aborted (core dumped)

my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

#include <sys/user.h>

#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  pid_t pid = fork();

  if(pid == 0)
  {
    //child
    char *data[] = { "throw", NULL};
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
    execve("./throw", data,NULL);
  }
  else
  {
    //parent
    int status = 0;
    //ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0); //I've seen examples of ptrace code where this doesn't seem to be necessary and I didn't notice a difference when I ran it.
    //Follow the children and kill them if we die
    int options = PTRACE_O_EXITKILL     | 
                PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE     | 
                PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORKDONE | 
                PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD   |
                PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK     | 
                PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK      |
                PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC;

    ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, options);

    user_regs_struct regs;

    long syscall = 0;

    while(1)
    {
      if(waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != pid)
      {
      unsigned long line = __LINE__;
      cerr << "Error in " << line <<  " " <<  strerror(errno) << endl;
      } 
               
      if(WIFSIGNALED(status))
      {
        cout << "Child signaled with rv of : " << WTERMSIG(status) << endl;
        if(WTERMSIG(status) == SIGABRT || WTERMSIG(status) == SIGIOT)
        {
          cout << "Child aborted!\n";
          return WTERMSIG(status);
        }
      }
      //should have entered the call. Doesn't matter too much if it repeats
      if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs) == -1)
      {
        unsigned long line = __LINE__;
        cerr << "Error in " << line <<  " " <<  strerror(errno) << endl;
      }

      syscall = regs.orig_rax;
      cout << "Call was: " << syscall << endl;

      if(ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0) == -1)
      {
        unsigned long line = __LINE__;
        cerr << "Error in " << line << " " <<  strerror(errno) << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}


Reference of syscall numbers
Output of my code:
--- 8< snip 8< ---
Call was: 9
Call was: 9
Call was: 10
Call was: 10
Call was: 56
Call was: 56
Call was: 202
In thread function
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
Child signaled with rv of : 6
Child aborted!

There are a few things that I see that my code isn't producing:

Signals aren't being shown despite calls to WIFSIGNALED(&status)
A lot of signals aren't being shown... all of the rt_sigprocmask are missing in addition to the tgkill. I know that I'm getting 'double syscall numbers' because ptrace will stop a tracee before a call to inspect arguments and after a call to get return value, so I'm not worried about that.

